# Android: Why is app RAM memory continuously growing?

Tags: android, android-activity, memory, ram

I am developing an app with `3 Activities` and I made some tests. I go from `Activity 1->2->3->1` and so on. I used `finish()` to close the activity I am leaving every time.But something happens:

[image: Ram stats]

The allocated `RAM` memory for my app is continuously growing, and I don't know why. `18MB` should be the lower limit because that's where app starts from and `24MB` should be the highest limit, because the `Garbage Collector` occurs when needed.

Even that it grows up to `36MB` in about 1 minute(in that time I go from one activity to another, nothing else).

Can someone tell me what happens? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that's not a problem. Your app memory is good. It increases on opening new activities and decreases again on closing activities. Am I right?

Comment: @HusseinElFeky You are right, but why is it rasing in another 2 stages(the ones where the red arrow points)? The app could manage the activities with a lower memory because I use finish() for every activity when I leave it, and just one activity is opened at a time.

Comment: That is the way Java manages memory. Memory usage increases until the garbage collector runs. Each memory usage drop in your diagram was caused by the garbage collector which released unused memory.

Comment: *Garbage collection occurs when needed*. And the runtime decides when it is needed. Having freed memory lying around is only a problem when it is needed elsewhere and that is exactly when the garbage collector is invoked. I cannot see a problem. The interesting points on the graph are actually those immediately past the GC runs, because if the used memory *after* a GC run is increasing, you might have a problem.

Comment: @Robert Yes, you can see where GC runs. But you can also see that after the second running of GC the memory is cleaned. Despite of that, a new limit is rised at 33mb, where my first red arraw points.

Comment: @dhke GC is running ok, but why is the max limit increasing? The max limit increase at 33mb after the second running of GC(second sawtooth). Is there an explication why is it working like that?

Answer (score 1):

The thing that I have experienced is, that it could be because of using high-res images.(Not high-sized)

Regards,
Gabriel

Comment: My Activities are basic, no images. Just a button on each activity. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Cristi         It can be because of Services and Timers,too, But as you mentioned that your activities are quite simple, I'm afraid I can't help you:(